# Basic python requests error when accessing website

Tags: python, web-scraping, plugins, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Running the script gives this unexpected token error and beautifulsoup error. I've looked at a LOT of guides and none seem to work. This would suggest a problem with my python setup rather than requests or BS. I've just `run apt-get remove python` and `get-get remove python-pip`, then reinstalled both.

Anyway, the output errors:

```
$./test.py
import-im6.q16: not authorized `urllib3' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
from: can't read /var/mail/bs4
./test.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.py: line 3: `http = urllib3.PoolManager()'
```

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'http://dustyfeet.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.data, 'lxml')
print (soup.title)
print (soup.title.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure python is executing this file?
Try running it with `$ python ./test.py` instead of `$ ./test.py` to ensure that your script is not being executed by the default shell.